# gfortran -fcray-pointer, best way to use pointers in fortran?

Tags: pointers, fortran, gfortran, fortran77, cray-pointers

I am not a fan of NEEDING numerous compiler flags to get a program to compile.  I generally see it as poor programming practice.
I have some old fortran code that uses the **POINTER** statement and when using gfortran to compile these files it responds with the error

`Error: Cray pointer declaration at (1) requires -fcray-pointer flag`

here is a sample of what is causing it

```
COMPLEX*16   matrix(1)
POINTER      (PM, mymatrix)
COMMON       /M_SHARED/  PM
```

if I use the intel compiler then there is no problem doing just  `ifort -O3 myprogram.f`  but I don't want to be dependent on needing the intel compiler.  I would prefer to be able to use gfortran which is free.

I would like to know how far behind the times my example is, and how it should be written properly.  Or should i just use the `-fcray-pointer` flag?

Comment: Are you asking how to rewrite the code without using Cray pointers (perhaps proper Fortran pointers)?

Comment: yes.  I only understand fortran because i know C.  I never took a course or stayed current on fortran programming practices.

Comment: Does your  tag `fortran77` means you want Fortran 77, or just that you code is something like Fortran 77? From your snippet it is clear it is not standard Fortran at all not even 77. Standard pointers were introduced in Fortran 90, there are described in many textbooks and tutorials.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fortran+cray+pointers

Comment: I want any code that successfully compiles and runs.  I did not write the existing code, which is a mess.

Comment: From your comments here I would say -- use the flag.  It is not a big deal to rewrite a pointer, but I take it that "files" means that there is some code there (not little) and if it is a "mess" you may get entangled.  Knowing C helps some but it doesn't substitute for knowing this language, specially when it comes to debugging. It seems far safer to just run that code since you can. If you really only want to know how to write a pointer that is simple.